# cordova wkwebview-engine-localhost plugin returning 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the cordova [wkwebview-engine-localhost](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost) plugin in my app to server up an exported inVison prototype.

So far my project file structure looks like shown below :

```
.
├── build.sh
├── config.xml
├── hooks
│   └── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── platforms
│   └── platforms.json
├── plugins
│   ├── fetch.json
│   └── ios.json
└── www
   ├── css
   │   └── index.css
   ├── external_app
   │   └── index.html
   ├── img
   │   └── logo.png
   ├── index.html
   └── js
    └── index.js
```

my config.xml looks like below :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="my.project.id" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>wkwvtest</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="http://localhost:0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<preference name="AlternateContentSrc" value="http://localhost:0" />
```

and I install the following plugins as shown below :

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins.git#master:wkwebview-engine-localhost
```

Then when I try to load the external_app index page as follows from the code written in index.js :

```
  var url = "external_app/index.html";
  console.log("opening the url : ", url);      
  cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'localtion=no');
```

The above code returns 403 forbidden error.

[image]

also my package.json looks like below :

```
{
  "name": "wkwvtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
  "urijs": "^1.18.4"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
 }
```

I am using ios cordova 4.3.1 and build using ios 9.0 in Xcode.

This works fine when I open as file:// instead of serving the file through the server.

Could anyone please point out what I am missing ?. Also feel free to revert back for any more clarifications and information.

Also I have uploaded my project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85vUqBPKLOxN2VSMV9SamhBYTA/view?usp=sharing). You can download and run the project on mac using the build.sh file. You will just need to have node and cordova installed.

Comment: Any ideas on this ?. I have also attached the sample project herewith.

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of the app in here how it looks on the Simulator itself.

Comment: Could someone pleas download my project from the given link and help me with a solution ?. It's been more than a month now. If not could someone please point me out what am I missing when asking this question ?.